# How to create an observable from pubnub subscribe

Tags: pubnub, rxjs

I'm struggling as to how to convert the following into observables using the rxjs lib.

```
var client = PUBNUB.init({
  publish_key: 'pubkey',
  subscribe_key: 'subkey'
});

client.subscribe({
  channel: 'admin:posts',
  message: function(message, env, channel){console.log("Message");},
  connect: function(){console.log("Connected");},
  disconnect: function(){console.log("Disconnected");},
  reconnect: function(){console.log("Reconnected");},
  error: function(){console.log("Network Error");}, 
 });
```

I would like to have the message callback converted into an observable along with the rest of those callbacks.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you

#### UPDATE - 4/29/15

Here is what I ended up using to get this working. I should add that I need to subscribe to pubnub only after the user signs in and clean up logout.

Please let me know if this is a good approach:

```
var self = this;

var logins = Rx.Observable.create(function (obs) {
  //Using a session manager in ember.
  self.get('session').on('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded', function(e){
    var data = {
      token:this.content.secure.token,
      email:this.content.secure.email
    }

    obs.onNext(data);
  });
  self.get('session').on('sessionAuthenticationFailed', function(e){obs.onError(e)});
  return function(){
    self.get('session').off('sessionAuthenticationSucceeded', function(e){obs.onNext(e)});
    self.get('session').off('sessionAuthenticationFailed', function(e){obs.onError(e)});
  }
});

var logouts = Rx.Observable.create(function (obs) {
  self.get('session').on('sessionInvalidationSucceeded', function(){obs.onNext()});
  self.get('session').on('sessionInvalidationFailed', function(e){obs.onError(e)});
  return function(){
    self.get('session').off('sessionInvalidationSucceeded', function(e){obs.onNext(e)});
    self.get('session').off('sessionInvalidationFailed', function(e){obs.onError(e)});
  }
});

var dataStream = logins
  .map(function(credentials){
    return PUBNUB.init({
      publish_key: 'pub_key',
      subscribe_key: 'sub_key',
      auth_key: credentials.token,
      uuid: credentials.email
    });
  })
  .scan(function(prev, current){
    prev.unsubscribe({
      channel_group:'admin:data'
    });

    return current;
  })
  .concatMap(function(client){
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

      client.subscribe({
        channel_group:'admin:data',
        message:function(message, env, channel){
          observer.onNext({message:message, env:env, channel:channel, error:null});
        },
        error:function(error){
          observer.onNext({error:error})
        }
      });

      return function(){
        client.unsubscribe({channel_group:'admin:data'});
      }
    });
  })
  .takeUntil(logouts)
  .publish()
  .refCount();

  var sub1 = dataStream.subscribe(function(data){
    console.log('sub1', data);
  });

  var sub2 = dataStream.subscribe(function(data){
    console.log('sub2', data);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can create a source as you with with `.create` as such:

```
// your client
var client = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'pubkey',
    subscribe_key: 'subkey'
});

var source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    client.subscribe({
         channel: 'admin:posts',
         message: function(message){ observer.onNext(message); }, // next item
         error: function(err){ observer.onError(message); },
         // other functions based on your logic, might want handling
    });
    return function(){ // dispose
        // nothing to do here, yet, you might want to define completion too
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 this is really close. Probably want to call unsubscribe in the disposable function, and also tack a `.singleInstance()`  on the end to make the Observable "cold" until subscribed to once, then "hot" thereafter until all subscribers have unsubscribed.  Also, might want to delay the PUBNUB.init until the first subscription, since it's a little expensive and modern apps usually have more than enough bootstrapping going on.

Comment: Oh hi there, didn't expect to see you on SO :) I left the lazy calls and unsubscribe to OP to specify since I'm not sure about his actual use - in our code I unsubscribe on dispose and handle reconnects/disconnects too - I just felt this is a strong assumption on his code but those are definitely good ideas for the typical use case.

Comment: Thank guys, I just added an update, any feedback on it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, would love to see the full code you are referring to.

Comment: I'd check if there is a way to use automatic conversion to observables and merging them instead of using explicit onNext and onError since you're using events - other than that it's ok'ish, blesh probably has more comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with PUBNUB but based on the information you've provided, I'd probably implement it like this:

```
// your client
var client = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'pubkey',
    subscribe_key: 'subkey'
});

var source = Rx.Observable.defer(function() {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        client.subscribe({
            channel: 'admin:posts',
            message: function(message){ observer.onNext(message); },
            connect: function(){console.log("Connected");},
            disconnect: function(){console.log("Disconnected");},
            reconnect: function(){console.log("Reconnected");},
            error: function(err){ observer.onError(err); }
        });

        return Rx.Disposable.create(function() { // dispose
            client.unsubscribe();
        });
    });
})
.publish()
.refCount();
```